# Continuous choropleth map in Leaflet

Tags: maps, leaflet

I want to create a continuous choropleth map in Leaflet.js. Specifically, I have a bunch of geographical points that I have data for (a value ranging from 0.0 to 1.0) and I want to create a map where each point on the map has a value interpolated from the nearest points for which data exist.

Is there a simple way to do this in Leaflet.js? I guess I could create a whole bunch of polygons to approximate a continuous map, but that would get heavy quick. Are there any plugins that do this, or is the best solution to write my own code with something like D3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While polygons may not be an ideal solution, they are easy to create with [Turf.tin](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_tin.html), so it's probably worth checking out. Say you have a GeoJSON object with a bunch of points, and they have a property called `size` that you would like to average over a TIN and display with with a color ramp. The following code will do that:

```js
var maxAvg = 0
var tin = turf.tin(dots, 'size')
for (var i = 0; i < tin.features.length; i++) {
  var properties  = tin.features[i].properties;
  properties.average = (properties.a+properties.b+properties.c)/3;
  if (properties.average > maxAvg) maxAvg = properties.average;
}

colorRamp = chroma.scale('YlGnBu');
L.geoJson(tin, {style: tinStyle}).addTo(map);

function tinStyle(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: colorRamp(feature.properties.average/maxAvg),
        weight: 0,
      fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}
```

I'm using [chroma.js](http://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#color-scales) to create the color ramp, but you could also create your own function (as in the Leaflet [choropleth example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html)). Here is a fiddle using this technique on some synthetic GeoJSON data:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/rku0pvLL/

This is using 1000 points, and it seems speedy enough. If you increase the `dotcount` to 10000, it gets noticeably slower, but not entirely unusable. Whether or not it works in your case will probably depend on how many points you have (and of course whether a TIN gives a smooth enough interpolation for your purposes).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly [Turf.js isolines](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_isolines.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: No, there is no interpolation there.

Comment: Well, it makes interpolated isolines (contour lines) and the density depends on how much breaks you pass as a parameter of the turf.isolines() function. Of course, it's not continuous but may work well.